# Как использовать MediaPlayer для получения текущего значения длины воспроизведения?

Tags: android

Как использовать MediaPlayer для получения текущего значения длины воспроизведения?

Пробовал через MediaController ничег не вышло. OnSeekComplete тоже не работает.

Есть у MediaPlayer какой нибудь слушатель который допустим каждую секунду узнает свой getCurrentDuration?

вот код

```
public class VideoControllerView implements View.OnClickListener{
private Context context;
private View viewController;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

private ImageButton back;
private ImageButton language;
private ImageButton subtitles;
private ImageButton quality;
private ImageButton prev;
private ImageButton play;
private ImageButton next;
private TextView leftTime;
private SeekBar seekBarTime;
private TextView leftRight;
private ImageButton fullScreen;

public VideoControllerView(Context context, View viewController, MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    this.context = context;
    this.viewController = viewController;
    this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
    initView();
}

public void setVisibleViewController(boolean bVisible){
    if (bVisible){
        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                viewController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }else {
        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                viewController.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}

public void initView(){
    //FindByID
    back= (ImageButton) viewController.findViewById(R.id.back);
    language= (ImageButton) viewController.findViewById(R.id.language);
    subtitles= (ImageButton) viewController.findViewById(R.id.subtitles);
    quality= (ImageButton) viewController.findViewById(R.id.quality);
    prev= (ImageButton) viewController.findViewById(R.id.prev);
    play= (ImageButton) viewController.findViewById(R.id.play);
    next= (ImageButton) viewController.findViewById(R.id.next);
    fullScreen= (ImageButton) viewController.findViewById(R.id.fullScreen);
    leftTime= (TextView) viewController.findViewById(R.id.leftTime);
    leftRight= (TextView) viewController.findViewById(R.id.leftRight);
    seekBarTime= (SeekBar) viewController.findViewById(R.id.seekBarTime);

    //ClickListener
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    language.setOnClickListener(this);
    subtitles.setOnClickListener(this);
    quality.setOnClickListener(this);
    prev.setOnClickListener(this);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    fullScreen.setOnClickListener(this);
    leftTime.setOnClickListener(this);
    leftRight.setOnClickListener(this);
    seekBarTime.setOnClickListener(this);

    Log.e("VideoControllerView=initView", mediaPlayer.getDuration() + "");
    seekBarTime.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.back:
            ((Activity)context).onBackPressed();
            break;
        case R.id.language:
            break;
        case R.id.subtitles:
            break;
        case R.id.quality:
            break;
        case R.id.prev:
            break;
        case R.id.play:
            break;
        case R.id.next:
            break;
        case R.id.leftTime:
            break;
        case R.id.seekBarTime:
            break;
        case R.id.leftRight:
            break;
        case R.id.fullScreen:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Конечно можно через таймер как то сделать. Но это уж слишком все велосипедно будет. Ведь не ужели в MediAPlayere уже нет готово решения?

---

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
player.prepareAsync();
```

///////////////////////

```
@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        View viewController = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.media_controller,null);
        addContentView(viewController,new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        videoControllerView=new VideoControllerView(WatchVideoActivity.this,viewController,player);
        player.start();
    }
```

Comment: Не усмотрел в вашем коде  `mediaPlayer.prepare()` без него вы не получите `duration` и проч. конфетки

Comment: @Barmaley, Обновил вопрос выше. Вообще я сам duration получаю. там у тестового файла где то 66102. У меня вопрос по поводу того чтобы привязать SeekBar к плееру. Чтобы когда видео воспроизводилось, то и SeekBar тоже двигался

Comment: @Barmaley, Просто таймер не подойдет. Ведь мне еще нужно и на нажатие ползунка реагировать

Comment: Просто таймер не подойдет. Ведь мне еще нужно и на нажатие ползунка реагировать –